# Python Multiprocessing Processes: Delay in recognizing Event when using Manager Queue

Tags: python, events, multiprocessing

I have the following codes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Event

manager = Manager()
shared_Queue = manager.Queue(10)
ev = Event()

def do_this(shared_queue, ev):
    while not ev.is_set():
        if not shared_Queue.__getattribute__('empty')():
           item = shared_queue.get()
           print item
    print 'released!'

subprocs = []
for i in xrange(10):
    subproc = Process(target=do_this, args=(shared_Queue, ev, ))
    subprocs.append(subproc)
    subproc.start()
```

now, if I run this, and I ask whether these processes are alive:

```
for subproc in subprocs: print subproc.is_alive()
```

of course I get all Trues.

After couple of doing these: * there is no error if I don't do these!

```
shared_Queue.put(3)
shared_Queue.put(5)
```

Now I want to set the Event to kill all of them using:

```
ev.set()
```

But then instead of seeing 'released!' 10 times, I get varying number of these prints, and after about 2 to 5 seconds, I get a bunch of errors:

```
released!
released!
released!
released!
released!
released!
released!
Process Process-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<input>", line 10, in do_this
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/managers.py", line 759, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
EOFError
Process Process-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<input>", line 10, in do_this
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/managers.py", line 759, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
EOFError
Process Process-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<input>", line 10, in do_this
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
multiprocessing/managers.py", line 759, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
EOFError
```

Why is it that some processes are unable to recognize the Event set and show up as errors later? Is there a better way to signal them to die?

Comment: _"set the Event to kill all of them"_, `ev.set()` don't kill anything! It sets only a condition to `True`! Your Traceback **does not** mirror your Example code!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment stovfl, you are right, ev.set() does not kill anything I was carelessly using the word.

As for the issue I was having, I learned that multiprocessing Queue is process and thread safe, meaning, my process will halt just before writing something into the Queue if the Queue is already full.

If I try to set the event while some of the processes are still waiting to write something to the full Queue, they will not recognize the event set.

The key was to empty all the Queue, let the process write to it, and the get to the first line where it can check on the event!